# Lucene difference between Term and Fields

Tags: lucene, search-engine, lucene.net

I've read a lot about Lucene indexing and searching and still can't understand what Term is?What is the difference between term and fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very rough analogy would be that *fields* are like columns in a database table, and *terms* are like the contents in each database column.

More specifically to Lucene:

### Terms

Terms are indexed tokens. See [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_2/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description):

> Lucene Analyzers are processing pipelines that break up text into indexed tokens, a.k.a. terms

So, for example, if you have the following sentence in a document...

```
"This is a list of terms"
```

...and you pass it through a whitespace tokenizer, this will generate the following terms:

```
This
is
a
list
of
terms
```

Terms are therefore also what you place into queries, when performing searches. See [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms) for a definition of how they are used in the classic query parser.

### Fields

A field is a section of a document.

A simple example is the *title* of a document versus the *body* (the remaining text/content) of the document. These can be defined as two separate Lucene fields within a Lucene index.

(You obviously need to be able to parse the source document so that you can separate the title from the body - otherwise you cannot populate each separate field correctly, while building your Lucene index.)

You can then place all of the title's *terms* into the *title* field; and the body's terms into the *body* field.

Now you can search title data separately from body data.

You can read about fields [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Fields) and [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_2/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html). There are various different types of fields, specific to the type of data (terms) they will be holding.